# Why does timestamp increase after a call to chill() but vtimestamp and walltimestamp do not?

Tags: freebsd, dtrace

I'd like to understand why calling `chill()` in a DTrace action block increases the `timestamp` variable, but not `vtimestamp` and `walltimestamp`.

Here's an example showing `timestamp` increasing after a call to `chill()`:

```
# dtrace -w -c true -n 'pid$target:::entry {self->t = $1; chill(1); printf("%d\n", $1 - self->t);}' timestamp
dtrace: description 'pid$target:::entry ' matched 3082 probes
dtrace: allowing destructive actions
dtrace: pid 6734 has exited
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  5  83475          _r_debug_postinit:entry 11258

  5  85771                     atexit:entry 2218

  5  86468              __libc_atexit:entry 491

  5  86428                       exit:entry 441

  5  85397    __cxa_thread_call_dtors:entry 441

  5  86213             __cxa_finalize:entry 447

  5  86213             __cxa_finalize:entry 565

  5  83470            _rtld_addr_phdr:entry 454

  5  86213             __cxa_finalize:entry 431

  5  83470            _rtld_addr_phdr:entry 1645

  5  84405                      _exit:entry 432
```

If we run the same script but use `walltimestamp` (or `vtimestamp`), we'll see the counter did not increase:

```
# dtrace -w -c true -n 'pid$target:::entry {self->t = $1; chill(1); printf("%d\n", $1 - self->t);}' walltimestamp
dtrace: description 'pid$target:::entry ' matched 3082 probes
dtrace: allowing destructive actions
dtrace: pid 6707 has exited
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  4  83475          _r_debug_postinit:entry 0

  4  85771                     atexit:entry 0

  4  86468              __libc_atexit:entry 0

  4  86428                       exit:entry 0

  4  85397    __cxa_thread_call_dtors:entry 0

  4  86213             __cxa_finalize:entry 0

  4  86213             __cxa_finalize:entry 0

  4  83470            _rtld_addr_phdr:entry 0

  4  86213             __cxa_finalize:entry 0

  4  83470            _rtld_addr_phdr:entry 0

  4  84405                      _exit:entry 0
```

This is understandable for `vtimestamp`, as it does not increase when executing DTrace code, but I don't understand `walltimestamp`'s behavior here.

I'm running FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE-p1 here on amd64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's a bug in DTrace. Apparently, the implementation of `chill()` only invalidates the cached value of the `timestamp` variable but not for `walltimestamp`, which is incorrect.

Thanks to Mark Johnston for providing the answer on the [FreeBSD DTrace mailing list](http://docs.FreeBSD.org/cgi/mid.cgi?Y34pG8Hdt6Ku5pM6).